# Special band names for sentinel-2 in QGIS SCP

Tags: batch-processing, qgis

I just started to work with QGIS. I would like to automatically calculate, for example,

```
NDMI=(NIR-SWIR)/(NIR+SWIR)=(B08-B11)/(B08+B11)
```

for Sentinel-2 and other indices that use bands other than the RGB/NIR ones when downloading a batch of Sen2 or Landsat-8 images in QGIS using the SCP plugin.

For this, I need to define a general formula with general names for the bands to be uploaded as a TXT file in the "Band calc" that will work on all the images. I know, for example, that the special name for Sen2 B08 is "#NIR#", but "#SWIR#" does not work for B11, probably because B11 is just one of the SWIR bands available in Sen2.

I couldn't find a list or table containing the special names for Sen2 and Landsat8 bands other than the RGB/NIR ones in the SCP documentation and on the internet. I would be very grateful if someone could post this information.

Answer (score 1):

Luca Congedo, the developer/owner of the SCP plugin, responded by e-mail that: "you can use the band number of the bandset for identifying bands in the band calc. For instance Sentinel-2 band 11 should be "bandset#b9" in the Band calc". In my case, the number of the bandset was 4, because I was downloding only the bands B2, B4, B8 and B11 of Sentinel-2, so I used "bandset#b4" in the formula. It worked perfectly.